# How to return the value of outer function when button inside inner function is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, currying

I have two buttons with the text ok and cancel.

```
<div class="buttons-div">
   <button class='cancel'>Cancel</button>
   <button class='ok'>Ok</button>
</div>
```

My functions are the following:

```
function outerFunc() {
   function innerFunc() {
     const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons-div')
       btns.forEach(btn => {
         btn.onclick = (e) => {
           if(e.target.classList.contains('cancel')) {
             return false;
           } else {
             return true;
           }
         }
       }
     )
   }
   
   return innerFunc()
}

const myBoolean = outerFunc()
```

I want to return a true or false value in `outerFunc()` when one of the two buttons is clicked.

Comment: Technically there is use of `outerFunc`, you can just remove it..

Comment: I am making custom confirm modal. So I am using other funcs inside this outerFunc too.

Comment: So why are you not using objects

Comment: Your inner function returns value only when a user click on element, so you can't catch it when you call it.

Comment: Can you guys tell me how I can do it? Hint

Comment: I think I gotta use objects as Manas Khandelwal said. I will try this way, then.

Comment: `btn.onclick` gets fired only when a button is clicked, it wont get executed right away once the main code is executed.

Comment: As it stands, innerFunc() is actually returning void - just because the click events that are assigned in innerFunc() are returning a boolean, they have no context in relation to the return of innerFunc(). Can you expand a little on the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here that you want to perform some action once either button is clicked, according to whether or not the OK/Cancel button was clicked. Would something like the following help you?

https://jsfiddle.net/8sy2mh4z/

```
function buttonClick(okClicked) { 
  console.log(okClicked);
  // TODO - implement logic based on button click
}

function initButtons() {

  document.querySelectorAll('.buttons-div').forEach(btn => {
    btn.onclick = (e) => {
      if(e.target.classList.contains('cancel')) {
        buttonClick(false);
      } else {
        buttonClick(true);
      }
    }
  });
}

initButtons();
```

Comment: @SardorekAminjonov was this answer helpful to you/did it solve your issue? If not, please expand a little and I will do my best to update accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In your `outerfunc`, add an event listener that monitors for the button's click.